# Why is my Cloud Firestore Transaction not merging when using SetOptions.merge()?

Tags: android, firebase, merge, google-cloud-firestore

Just started with Firestore and use the [`SetOptions.merge()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) in a Cloud Firestore Transaction like this nothing special I guess:

```
final Map<String, Object> visitorMap = new HashMap<>();
visitorMap.put(Visitor.NOTIFY_ON_CHAT_MESSAGE, true);
visitorMap.put(Visitor.TIME, FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
final DocumentReference docRefVisitor = mFirestore
        .collection(VISITORS)
        .document(theId)
        .collection(VISITORS_USER)
        .document(getCurrentUser().getUserId());
mFirestore.runTransaction(new com.google.firebase.firestore.Transaction.Function<void>() {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public void apply(@NonNull Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {
        transaction.set(docRefVisitor, visitorMap, SetOptions.merge());
    }
})
```

The docs say:

> If the document does not exist, it will be created. If the document
>   does exist, its contents will be overwritten with the newly provided
>   data, unless you specify that the data should be merged into the
>   existing document

I experience that `Visitor.NOTIFY_ON_CHAT_MESSAGE` `boolean` is overwriting existing `boolean` at Cloud Firestore database Document. I though the `SetOptions.merge()` would not overwrite existing values?
Maybe I missed something about how [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) works or this is a Beta related thing since CF is Beta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding `SetOptions merge()` method as the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/android/SetOptions.html#merge()) says:

> Changes the behavior of set() calls to only replace the values specified in its data argument. Fields omitted from the set() call will remain untouched.

So `SetOptions.merge()` method will only replace the fields under fieldPaths. Any field that is not specified in fieldPaths is ignored and remains untouched.

As a conslusion, if the document does not exist, it will be created. If the document does exist, its contents `will be overwritten` with the newly provided data, unless you specify that the data should be merged into the existing document, as follows:

```
// Update one field, creating the document if it does not already exist.
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("Visitor.NOTIFY_ON_CHAT_MESSAGE", true);
docRefVisitor.set(data, SetOptions.merge());
```

Comment: In my case if datatype is Object in Firestore, than not merging data of that key.

Comment: @MehulSojitra Please post a fresh question regarding your issue, so me and other users can help you.