# Firestore: Updating field in an object removes previous field

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Flutter cloud firestore. Here is how my database looks like.

[image]

I want to add more fields (like "2222") in `a_numbers` object. I use `updateData()`like this,

```
DocumentReference ref = Firestore.instance.document("products/-LMhR5cAyW4T0sa03UtU");
ref.updateData({"a_numbers": {"2222" : false}});
```

The above snippet basically deletes the previous value (1111) and then updates the database with 2222 field.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

To update 'a_numbers' with Pair without removing the previous values, you should assign the reference path (example: 'a_number.2222') to K and assign value to V. I edited your code. please review it for more information.

```
DocumentReference ref = Firestore.instance.document("products/-LMhR5cAyW4T0sa03UtU");
ref.updateData({'a_numbers.2222': value});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior, in your Flutter application, you need to store `a_numbers` in a `Map` and add any new `(key,value)` pairs using `myMap.addAll({key:value})`, then you can use `ref.updateData(myMap)`

Comment: You mean first I need to retrieve all the data (in form of map) and then use `updateData()` method? In this case what is the use of using `updateData()`, you can use `setData()` too. And also you would have lots of read write operation just to add one field. Not good in my opinion.

Comment: this is because the way you structured your data, update data will only work on the first class fields inside of a document, that is the very first tree of fields under the document so it will update just these fields without the need to overwrite, however you are updating a nested field so you need to store the current value, append on it then update. it is just the way updating a doc in firestore works, it only updates the top level fields in the doc

Comment: I found a solution but that only works in Android (native), the Firebase team will definitely find out a solution for this. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47365970/why-is-my-cloud-firestore-transaction-not-merging-when-using-setoptions-merge), there is `SetOptions` class that Flutter is missing. Otherwise everything works fine.