# How to use SetOptions.merge with .set() when writing to Firestore in Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that creates a Firestore entry when a new user is registered

```
exports.newUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

  var userObject = {
     displayName : user.displayName,
     picUrl:user.photoURL,
     authType:user.providerData,
     email : user.email,
     newUser: true,
     bookings:0
  };

  console.log("Merge:true")
  return admin.firestore().doc('users/'+user.uid).set(userObject, SetOptions.merge())
  .then((response)=>{
    console.log("New user result: ",response)
    return response;
  }).catch((err)=>
  {
    console.log("New user Error: "+err)
    return err;
  });
});
```

I want to use setoptions.merge() but It is not working, I want to update because I am also writing the device token on firestore for FCM messages.

> NewUser ReferenceError: SetOptions is not defined at
>   exports.newUser.functions.auth.user.onCreate (/srv/index.js:26:67) at
>   cloudFunction
>   (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
>   at /worker/worker.js:825:24 at  at

I refered the google cloud documentation where they said to pass it as {merge:true} but that also didn't help.
I refered this post on stackoverflow [Why is my Cloud Firestore Transaction not merging when using SetOptions.merge()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47365970/why-is-my-cloud-firestore-transaction-not-merging-when-using-setoptions-merge)
But this also didn't work.
Please help me as I don't know much about firestore cloud functions

Comment: What you are doing now won't work.  The documentation is pretty clear that you are supposed to pass `{merge:true}`.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: The problem was with user.providerData which return as json object with a **function**  which was causing the encoding error. as for merge options, it is **.set(data,{merge:true})**

Comment: If you are saying that there's no longer a problem, please delete the question or simply answer your own question.

Comment: Could you confirm that you have resolved the issue?

Comment: Yes @EnriqueDelValle my problem was solved.

Answer (score 6):

The problem was with **user.providerData** which return as json object with a function which was causing the encoding error. As for merge options, it is `.set(data,{merge:true})`